# Pandas to understand inconsistent seperator for csv files

Tags: python, pandas

Depending on the regional settings the csv file exported from excel may be different thus giving me error in my script. Therefore i m thinking what is the best way to fix this issue.
Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: You mean where the delimiter is different? Pretty sure that you could define the delimiter as required.

Comment: i mean that i have a web app that users are uploading their .csv files. Currently i have set pandas to read csv with comma seperator. But some users have complained getting error on running the app and the reason is because of the delimiter that they use when exporting csv from excel.

Comment: New excel as far as I know is using semicolons as delimiter. You could do a try except clause with the custom delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following snippet:

```
import csv
sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
sample_bytes = 32
dialect = sniffer.sniff(open("semicolons.csv").read(sample_bytes))

print dialect.delimiter
```

source: https://www.kite.com/python/examples/3323/csv-sniff-a-sample-of-a-csv-file-to-determine-its-dialect